# cannot navigate between screens, expo says the following errror , undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, stack-navigator

i am a newbie working on react- native. I am trying to use the react native stack navigator to move between screens. while working the same with function it works. with the class component i could not able to get the output. Is there anything i need to import to the LoginPage.js file before i work?

i have my 'app.js' as follows

```
// importing dependencies
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'


// importing screens
import LoginPage from './LoginPage'
import ControlScreen from './ControlScreen'
import UpdateProfile from './UpdateProfile'
import GetDetails from './GetDetails'


// creating stack navigator
const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()

    this.state={
      SignedIn : 0
    }
  }

  SignedInChecker= ()=>{

    if(this.state.SignedIn===0){
      return({
        name : 'loginpage',
        component :LoginPage,
        Oname : 'control',
        Ocomponent :ControlScreen       
      })
    }
    else
    return({
      name : 'control',
      component :ControlScreen,
      Oname : 'loginpage',
      Ocomponent :LoginPage,
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (      
      <NavigationContainer >
        <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName={this.SignedInChecker().name} headerMode ='none' screenOptions ={{headerTitleAlign:'center',}}>
          <StackNav.Screen name={this.SignedInChecker().name} component={this.SignedInChecker().component} />
          <StackNav.Screen name={this.SignedInChecker().Oname} component={this.SignedInChecker().Ocomponent}/>    
          <StackNav.Screen name='UpdateProfile' component={UpdateProfile} />       
          <StackNav.Screen name='GetDetails' component={GetDetails} />    
       </StackNav.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>

    );
  }
}
```

---

my LoginPage.js has the following code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button,View,StyleSheet,Text,SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';


import GetDetails from './GetDetails'

class LoginPage extends Component(){
 constructor(props){
   super(props)


 }
  render(){
    return(
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>
        <Button onPress ={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('GetDetails')} title='go to getdetails'/ >
        </Text>
      </SafeAreaView>

    )
  }
} 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    marginStart:20,
    marginTop:25,
    alignItems:'center'
      }
})

export default LoginPage;
```

---

when i use expo i get a error () undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: did you log the props, it seems that the navigation prop is null , thats why it throws that error

Comment: what code should I add in here.. because if i try to log to console also i get the same error at expo